# HOw to convert 2015-12-08T17:52:36 to AM and Pm that is 12 hours

Tags: ios

How to convert 2015-12-08T17:52:36 to AM and Pm that is 12 hours

My code goes here

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *str = dateString;
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSTimeZone *pdt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:pdt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString * updatedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

It is working fine in iOS 8 but it is returning nill in iOS 9

Comment: What exactly your issue is ?

Comment: In ios 8 same code works fine i am able to get time string in Am /Pm formate but in ios 9 it is not getting

Comment: @nagarocks what is the dateString value that u r passing ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this: dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a.  Be sure to use "hh" in lower case. Let me know if this helps.